# How to get a SQL where function to reference an excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to append data to a report in my excel spreadsheet. I only want data that is greater than the maximum insertdatetime (which is column H) inserted into a sheet called Aging_Table.

Below is my code.

```
INSERT INTO [Table_Query_from_RFMS] (Store, Cust_Name,MgmtCo,   
Inv_Num,    Del_Date,   Balance,    CustPONum,  InsertedDateTime)
SELECT Header.Store, 
'MgmtCo' =
case when charindex('-',ISNULL(r.cust_name, 'Mgmt Co. Relationship not defined'))<2 
       then ISNULL(Convert(varchar(60),r.cust_name), 'Mgmt Co. Relationship not defined')
   else
       Left
       (
       ISNULL(Convert(varchar(60),r.cust_name), 'Mgmt Co. Relationship not defined'),
       charindex('-',ISNULL(Convert(varchar(60),r.cust_name), 
'Mgmt Co. Relationship not defined'))-1
       )
   end,Header.Cust_Name, Header.Inv_Num,header.CustPONum, Header.Del_Date, Header.Balance, header.InsertedDateTime

FROM Header Header
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Customer Customer on Customer.Cust_name = Header.Cust_name
   left join customer r
       on customer.referringmember = r.seqnum
WHERE (Header.Inv_Num Not Like 'CL%') 
And (Header.Voided = 0) and (Header.Cust_Name not like 
'%*VOID*%')
/*and (Header.Cust_Name like 
'')*/
and(((Header.Del_Date <> '')
and (Header.Balance <> 0))
or header.balance < 0)
and header.InsertedDateTime > max([Aging_Table$H:H])
ORDER BY Header.Store, Header.Salesman1, Header.Cust_Name
```

Comment: Where are you executing this SQL from exactly?

Comment: It is an ODBC Database Query connection in my excel file.